# Failed WebSocket Connection (Pusher.com and Laravel)

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher

I have a problem with websocket connection.
This is the error in the browser. I am getting a message in pusher.com just then I refresh the page, but not every time the websocket connects. I think something is wrong with my .env file, but not sure.
[image]

.env file:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=...
PUSHER_APP_KEY=...
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=...
PUSHER_HOST=null
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
```

What host should I write to solve it? Or the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to Pusher you do not need to set the host or port. You can remove these variables and then the library will be able to connect to Pusher.